# Flask site on Heroku continuously boots workers with new PIDs

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, heroku, gunicorn

I have a Flask app that I am hosting on Heroku as part of a science fair project. I've run into an issue that I seemingly cannot solve.

When I run the app locally everything runs fine and even when I use `heroku local web` locally everything works fine.

However, when I deploy to Heroku I continously get the below message:
[image]

Workers simply boot infinitely and I cannot access the site because it seems to just time out.

This is my requirements.txt:

```
gunicorn==20.0.4
Jinja2==2.11.2
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.19.4
opencv-python-headless==4.4.0.46
Pillow==8.0.1
protobuf==3.14.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
tensorflow-cpu==2.4.0
```

Procfile: `web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:app`

App.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, request, redirect, send_from_directory
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from project import main
import os
import cv2
import time
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import PIL

UPLOAD_FOLDER = "static"
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = ('jpg','jpeg')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER 


@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET','POST'])
def show_index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/success', methods = ['POST']) 
def success():  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        filelist = [f for f in os.listdir("static")]
        for f in filelist:
            os.remove(os.path.join("static", f))  
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],secure_filename(f.filename)))
        images = [f for f in os.listdir("static")]
        print(images)
        image = cv2.imread("static/" + str(images[0]))
        img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
            "static/" + str(images[0]), target_size=(180, 180)
        )
        img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
        img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) # Create a batch

        
        my_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model/content/my_model')
        predictions = my_model.predict(img_array)
        score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

        class_names = ['floorplan', 'random image', 'maze']
        model="The machine learning model predicts that this image is a {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence.".format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
        print(
            "The machine learning model predicts that this image is a {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence."
            .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
            
        )
        morphSuggestion = ""
        if np.argmax(score) == 0:
            morphSuggestion = "Based on the fact that we predict this is a floorplan, we recommend enabling the morphological transformation below."
        elif np.argmax(score) == 1:
            morphSuggestion = "This is does not appear to be a floorplan or any discernible image. Therefore, please be prepared for unexpected results."
        elif np.argmax(score) == 2:
            moprhSuggestion = "This appears to be a maze. Therefore, we suggest you do not enable morphological transformations as mazes are not what our program is enabled to easily operate on."
        

        
        images = [f for f in os.listdir("static")]
        image = cv2.imread("static/" + str(images[0]))
        dim = None
        filename = str(time.time()) + str(images[0])
        if(image.shape[0] > 700):
            r = 700 / float(image.shape[0])
            dim = (int(image.shape[1] * r), 700)
            image = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            filelist = [f for f in os.listdir("static")]
            for f in filelist:
                os.remove(os.path.join("static", f))  
        cv2.imwrite("static/" + filename,image)
        return render_template("success.html", name = filename,user_image=filename,model=model,morphSuggest=morphSuggestion)

@app.route('/algorithm',methods=['POST'])
def algorithm():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form['startingX'])
        print(request.form['startingY'])
        images = [f for f in os.listdir("static")]
        image = cv2.imread("static/" + str(images[0]))
        if(request.form['morph'] == "true"):
            morphBool = True
        else:
            morphBool = False
        path = main("static/" + str(images[0]), int(request.form['startingX']), int(request.form['startingY']), 
        int(request.form['goalX']), int(request.form['goalY']), morphBool)
        dim = None
        if(image.shape[0] > 700):
            r = 700 / float(image.shape[0])
            dim = (int(image.shape[1] * r), 700)
            image = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        for i in path:
            image[i[0],i[1]] = [0,0,255]
        filename = str(time.time()) + "image.jpg"
        filelist = [f for f in os.listdir("static")]
        for f in filelist:
            os.remove(os.path.join("static", f))
        cv2.imwrite("static/" + filename,image)
        #full_filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'floorplan2.jpg')
        return render_template("algorithm.html",user_image=filename) 



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I will note that my slug is over the soft limit of 300 MB at 382 MB but it is still under that 500 MB limit. I just don't even know where to begin with solving this because of the lack of an error message. I am also not using Docker with this.

Something of importance is that I was able to deploy the site once when I did not have tensorflow but now seemingly with the addition of tensorflow the site simply does not work.

Comment: Please say more about "when I did not have tensorflow but now seemingly with the addition of tensorflow the site simply does not work". You've told us about your `web` process, but the error is with a `worker` process that may be whatever you're doing with TensorFlow.

Comment: So basically the gist of my site is that I am using an A* Algorithm to find shortest paths in images. Before, this was all my site did. You simply uploaded an image and then my algorithm would solve a shortest path that between two coordinates that you inputted. Deployment was successful with just this. Another part of my project was that I was using Tensorflow to do image recognition to determine if an image was truly a floorplan or if it was some other random image (this model is functional and does work in localhost). Once I tried to deploy it into Heroku, my site no longer worked.

Comment: Are you using a worker for any of that?

Comment: I am actually not using a worker for any of this. I am admittedly new to this whole DevOps type of thing. Is that something I must use for such a process? Additionally, if I should be using it would it fix my above issue. I am fine with slower speeds as this is just a project that conceivably only one person at a time would be using but I would like to at least get the site working (even at slower speeds).

Comment: Your errors are about workers. I'm just trying to understand where they come from. Are you spawning new processes?

Comment: At no point have I done anything to explicitly spawn new processes in my code. I am not even sure if it is possible to do that by accident. My Github repo is: https://github.com/avayedawadi/AStarAlgorithm for this project. In the code, I have never thought about spawning new processes so I imagine that the answer to your question would be no.